# What's the best way to compute the offset of a time series?

Tags: time-series, inference

Say that I have a signal $f(t)$ composed of an offset, another signal and noise:

$$
f(t) = offset + g(t) + \epsilon(t)
$$

The function $g(t)$ is strictly possitive but the epsilon can make the observation just below and above the offset. Given $f(t)$ what is the best statistically sound way of getting the offset?

---

As an example how would you answer $offset=5$ when analyzing the following signal

```
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0,100,101)
signal = 5 + np.abs(np.sin(2*np.pi*t/25)) + 0.2*np.random.randn(len(t))
```